# 403 Forbidden trying to embed a Power BI report

Tags: powerbi, embedding, powerbi-embedded

I am trying to embed a Power BI report in a Vue/Nuxt app without success.
We are implementing against the App Owns Data model.

I can successfully retrieve an access token and generate an embed token for a specific report.

The tokens generated, and the report id I have, successfully resolve and embed the report via the Power BI Playground, so I know we have the correct details and permissions.

I am also using the official Power BI Client package from Microsoft to perform the embed:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/powerbi-client

When I try, I get the following:

[image: Power BI embed failed with 403]

I've confirmed that the Service Principal has admin rights to all workspaces, and the report I'm testing has been re-published to ensure it has the latest permissions, without success.

This is the code being implemented (with the data being passed via route currently):

```
<template>
    <v-container
        fluid
        class="ma-0 pa-0"
    >
        <v-row class="app-bar ma-0 py-0 px-6">
            <v-col
                cols="12"
                class="px-0"
            >
                <NuxtLink to="/"
                    ><v-icon
                        color="#2670ca"
                        size="x-large"
                        >mdi-chevron-left
                    </v-icon>
                </NuxtLink>
                <div class="pl-3">{{ reportName }}</div>
            </v-col>
        </v-row>
    </v-container>
    <v-container
        fluid
        class="ma-0 pa-0 fill-height"
    >
        <div
            id="report-container"
            ref="reportContainer"
            width="100%"
            height="100%"
            style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; flex: 1 1 auto; max-width: 100%"
        ></div>
    </v-container>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
    import { onMounted } from "vue";
    import * as pbi from "powerbi-client";
    const route = useRoute();
    const user = useSupabaseUser();
    console.log("Confirming login...");
    watch(
        user,
        () => {
            if (!user.value) {
                return navigateTo("/login");
            }
        },
        { immediate: true }
    );
    const reportName = computed(() => (route.query.name === undefined ? "Unknown" : String(route.query.name)));

    console.log("Available permissions...");
    console.log(pbi.models);

    onMounted(() => {
        // Set up the configuration object that determines what to embed and how to embed it.
        let embedConfiguration = {
            // Incorrect: Using EntraID token
            // accessToken: route.query.accessToken?.toString(),
            // Correct: Using token from Generate Power Bi Token response
            // Note: I've added state management since
            accessToken: authStore.pbiToken,
            embedUrl: route.query.embedUrl?.toString(),
            id: route.query.id?.toString(),
            permissions: pbi.models.Permissions.Read,
            tokenType: pbi.models.TokenType.Embed,
            type: route.query.reportType?.toString(),
            pageView: "fitToWidth",
        };

        console.log("Check embed configuration...");
        console.log({ embedConfiguration: embedConfiguration });

        let powerbi = new pbi.service.Service(pbi.factories.hpmFactory, pbi.factories.wpmpFactory, pbi.factories.routerFactory);

        // Get a reference to the HTML element that contains the embedded report.
        let embedContainer = document.getElementById("report-container")!;

        // Embed the report or dashboard.
        let report = powerbi.embed(embedContainer, embedConfiguration);
    
        report.off("loaded");
        report.off("rendered");
        report.on("error", function (err) {
            console.log("Embed report error:");
            console.log({ embedError: err });
            report.off("error");
        });
    });
</script>
```

What could be missing/incorrect in our configuration/code that is not obvious from the MS docs?

**EDIT**

Something that does seem curious. I am making this call from New Zealand. When I request the access token at say 8:49 am on the 25 March (2024-03-25) the expiration date that comes back already seems invalid... i.e. timezone, etc.

[image: Is the expiration date already invalid]

*Resolved: The time looks the same but 12 hrs out... however, being UTC it was not obvious that daylight savings was counted for, so the actual time was an hour earlier, meaning the 1 hour token expiry was valid.*

**EDIT 2**

Have confirmed that my user has read permissions to the report I'm trying to view.

**EDIT 3**

I have tried against a Pro PBI License and still no luck.

The error message above: "403 Forbidden - Fail to initialise - Cannot resolve cluster" is described by MS as "Wrong token type or bad token". At this point I'm sure we are implementing via the App Owns Data method so the token type of "Embed" is correct.

How is one supposed to know if their token is 'bad'?, let alone what's wrong with it and how to fix it!

**EDIT 4**

The code I use to generate the access token is below, but I do not recall seeing anything about specifying a tokenType in the request body!?

```
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
    const runtimeConfig = useRuntimeConfig(event);
    const params = {
        client_id: String(runtimeConfig.pbClientId),
        client_secret: String(runtimeConfig.pbClientSecret),
        grant_type: "client_credentials",
        scope: "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default",
        authorityUrl: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/",
    };
    const requestParams = new URLSearchParams(params);
    const getAccessTokenResponse = await $fetch(`https://login.microsoftonline.com/${runtimeConfig.pcTenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token`, {
        method: "POST",
        mode: "no-cors",
        body: requestParams,
    });
    console.log({ type: "API DEBUG", intent: "Get token to access Power BI resources", result: getAccessTokenResponse });
    return {
        data: getAccessTokenResponse,
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Troubleshoot](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/developer/embedded/embedded-troubleshoot#typical-errors-when-embedding-for-power-bi-users) documentation, the reason for the error might be bad access Token or Embed Token type doesn't match the token type.

There is no information how you're generating the access Token in the question.

1. If you're generating the access Token by hitting endpoint `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token`, Make sure you pass the scope for eg `https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default`.
   In this scenario the Token type will be `models.TokenType.Aad` and need to update it in your embedConfig.
2. If you're getting accessToken by hitting the Embedded Rest APIs [Generate Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/power-bi/embed-token/generate-token), then the Token type will be of `models.TokenType.Embed`.
   In order to generate the Embed Token, use the above token generated by you, Hit the [Generate Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/embed-token/generate-token) REST API by passing your previous token as a bearer token and you will get a new Token in the Response and it will be of type `Embed`. Use that token to Embed the report.

If the issue still exists, need to provide more details on how you're generating the access Token.

Comment: I've added my access token request code (EDIT 4)... and like my edit says, I don't recall a tokenType being specified... what documentation are you looking at to confirm this? just so I can verify and then confirm I am in fact - legally blind :P

Comment: Wait a minute... what you're saying is, if I generate the access token via method #1... then the tokenType for my embed should be Aad... otherwise is should be Embed? Except, everything I recall reading said, if you're using App Owns Data - Use Embed, otherwise use Aad. I am so confused by Microsoft's documentation LOL

Comment: Yes, it's recommended to use Embed Token for Apps Own data as it provides additional features to the token. But in the above scenario if you pass Token type as `Aad` it should work, and you should be able to embed the report. You can give it a try and it should work. LMK if it works or not

Comment: @JeremyW,  If not, Updated my response on how to generate the Embed Token from using the token generated by you. Please go through my above comment and updated response and LMK if you're still facing issues

Comment: Thanks @kotana-sai what you said yesterday made me realise this was the issue. I just didn't get a chance to try it. After your latest reply confirming so, sure enough it worked. Now it's like... duhh, of course... but when all the docs specify "get access token from MS to access resource... then specify a property on the embed config called accessToken... one gets a tad blind to what - now - makes sooo much sense. Thank you so much for your assistance. I've updated my code with the correct token returned from the GenerateToken endpoint for the embed configuration.